# javascript int to binary but print is infinity

Tags: javascript

```
  data = parseInt(num);  
  bin =0;
  pow=1;
  var rem=0 ;
 while(data != 0){
  rem = data % 2;
 data = data / 2;
  bin = rem * pow + bin;
  pow = pow *10;
  }

  document.write(bin);
```

for example 53 is 110110. but print is infinity in javascript. Where is my fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
parseInt('53').toString(2); // returns 110110
```

or just

```
(53).toString(2);
```

full:

```
var num = prompt("Please enter an integer between 0 and 255", "");

document.write(parseInt(num, 10).toString(2));
```

Comment: Is a num variable string or number?

Comment: num=prompt("Please enter an integer between 0 and 255", "");
data = parseInt(num);
That means it is int; num

Comment: it is operational-ready function. I have to use my func and toString(2) why 2 is there?

Comment: 2 is there to convert original number to base-2 and then make it string.